# OCL allInstances()

Tags: ocl

At time i learning OCL a little and come across following question, which i coundn't find the right answer. I looked in the documentation on [OCL 2.4 Spec](https://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4/), but i found nothing, that seem to answer my question:

Mostly *allInstances()* examples are used as follow:

context Person inv:
Person.allInstances().forAll(p : Person | p.employeeNumber <> self.employeeNumber)

where *Person* is a class with the attribute *employeeNumber*.

Is it also allowed to use *allInstances()* on self and other attributes, and would be have the same, like *<Type>.allInstances()*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting one of the vaguer areas of the OCL spec. allInstances() is a type operation and so might be considered static but the static keyword was added in OCL 2.2 without any clear semantics or examples.

The Eclipse OCL Pivot-based implementation prototypes a resolution of the vaguenesses. OclElement::allInstances() is modelled as a static operation in /org.eclipse.ocl.pivot/model/OCL-2.5.oclstdlib and so the source must be a type.

If you invoke self.allInstances() you get "'Class' rather than 'Object' value required".

If you invoke self.oclType().allInstances() you get something more interesting.

NB. implementing oclType() to support full reflection is another specification clarification.

If you want portability between OCL implementations stick to something like Person.allInstances()->isUnique(employeeNumber).

Comment: Not sure if i understand that right, eclipse does not allow self.allInstances(). NB stands for NetBeans? and does it allow it?

Comment: (split for length) When i look at the documentation under 7.5.10 there it make it clear, that static features from the model can be used using "::" operator. Where it gets confusing is "It is an operation applicable to instances of the Classifier metaclass" I don't know what a metaclass is in OCL and didn't find it so far. My thought so far was from the more c and Variants view. Objects are instances of a "class" and so far i understand that seems to be a metaclass.

Comment: NB is Nota Bene.